# Seperate Body/Header in logic app custom connector

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

Hi have an ARM Template that deploys some custom connectors. I have a connector called `Start` in that when i try to use this below piece of code which sets message body and header seperately it works fine. But when i do the same on a following connector , Assue `Connector-Start` as A and its followed by connector B. The input is not showing in different fields. Instead its not even relevant. can anyone help.

In the connector `parameters` here's the first block

```
{
                    "name": "Body",
                    "in": "body",
                    "schema": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "MessageBody": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "description": "Message body passed to the http trigger"
                        },
                        "MessageHeader": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "description": "Message header passed to the http trigger"
                        }
                      },
                      "required": [
                        "MessageBody",
                        "MessageHeader"
                      ]
                    },
                    "description": "Message body to get properties from the message payload.",
                    "required": true
                  },
```

Here's the input shown in portal for `connector-A`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, after deployment the old connector is cached. Removing it and adding it again worked.